# Restkit- How to display the json data in a table view

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, restkit, restkit-0.20

I've created an application using rest kit 0.20.3 and xcode 5. I've created 2 objects on my server. But I'm unable to display the data in the tableview. Below is the code for my table view:
PlayerViewController.m

```
#import "PlayerViewController.h"
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import "Player.h"

@interface PlayerViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlayerViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(loadPlayers) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;

    [self loadPlayers];
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

}

-(void)loadPlayers{

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/players.json" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"An Error Has Occurred" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return players.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PlayerCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Player *player = [players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = player.playerName;

    return cell;
}
```

the players array count shows 0. I know i'm missing something here, but can't seem to figure it out. 
Thank You.

Comment: where are you assigning the data you just downloaded to the array `players`?

Comment: I don't how to set the array with 2 players object that i received. Can u pls tell me how to do it.

Comment: it depends on the format that the data has coming from the server.

Comment: the data is in json format.

Comment: then @Firo's answer would probably work! Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the data to your players array:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/players.json" 
                                       parameters:nil 
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, 
                                                    RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    self.players = mappingResult.array; // <-- doing the actual assignment
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
} // ... the rest of your code
```

This assumes you have have your mappings correct.

Comment: Thanks man! It worked. Actually I've earlier created an NSMutableArray, so it wasn't working in the line        self.players = mappingResult.array;      So I changed it to NSArray and it worked...silly mistake. But Thanks anyways!

Comment: If you want to keep it an `NSMutableArray` (for whatever reason) just do: `self.players = [mappingResult.array mutableCopy];` Also, glad it worked!